# How can I make nginx recognise directories with spaces in its name?

Tags: nginx

I want to move a website from /var/www/WebSite to /media/Backed Websites/Website. I can't make nginx recognise the "Backed Website" directory. Tried with quotes, with the \,but no success. Any idea? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible. We can't use \, though. Single and double quotes are expected to work, especially on root directive. So, you could try single quotes.

BTW, which version of Nginx are you using?

Comment: 1.1.14 Quoting the whole path seems to work.

Comment: Glad to know it works!

Comment: i cannot get this to work, hmm